# No class named AppDelegate is loaded

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

We have a Xamarin.iOS project that shares a code backend with a WPF project that has been going through a refactor.  All the shared code libraries have been converted to be .net standard.

The Xamarin project builds, but the simulator throws an exception on startup as such :

> Foundation.MonoTouchException has been thrown
>
> Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Unable to instantiate the UIApplication delegate instance. No class named AppDelegate is loaded.

Just for testing purposes, I added an empty UIApplicationDelegate to Main.cs and I'll still get the exception (only now referring to TestDelegate).

Main.cs

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace App.IOS
{
    public class Application
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            UIApplication.Main (args, null, nameof(AppDelegate));
        }
    }
}
```

Appdelegate.cs (very large file, so just the declarations here).

```
namespace App.IOS
{
    public class MiniSetup
    {
        public static readonly MiniSetup Instance = new MiniSetup ();
        public void EnsureInit()
        {
            //Setting up Binding and Dependency Injection Here.
        }
    }
    

    [Register (nameof(AppDelegate))]
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            //Invoke Minisetup here
        }
        public override void WillEnterForeground (UIApplication application)
        {
            //snip
        }
        public override void DidEnterBackground (UIApplication 

application)
            {
                //snip
            }

// snip other code for setting UI controls and other app logic.
        }
```

It seems apparent that I've goofed up the project in some way, but I haven't found any leads as to where to look for a solution.  Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a smoking gun here, but near as I was able to figure out, an incompatible (with xamarin) reference or nuget package was added to the IOS project.  While the native code was throwing a native assembly, I'd imagine that AppDelegate was actually throwing a NotSupportedException or an AssemblyLoader Exception or similar.

So removing all references and nuget packages, then re-adding just the bare minimum seems to have resolved this issue.

Comment: I also have the same issue. so I remove all my references and nuget packages and re-add all, but still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Two classed needed, the `UIApplicationDelegate` subclass and the class that defines the `Main` entry point that calls `UIApplication.Main` will the `Xamarin.iOS` registered name that you used on the `UIApplicationDelegate` subclass.

#### Basic/Minimum UIApplicationDelegate:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    public override UIWindow Window
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

#### Basic/Minimum Main entry point:

```
public class Application
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I've got, verbatim.  I moved the AppDelegate class (TestDelegate, in my snippet) to be in the same namespace and file as Application, just to rule that out.

Comment: @Brandorf your 'testdelegate' needs to be the same name as the paramater in the UIApplication.Main() method, so just change it to "AppDelegate".

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt They are, code is as it is in the snippet, unless I'm completely misunderstanding something.

Comment: @Brandorf Can you add you complete application class and UIApplicationDelegate class to your question.

Comment: I've done so, our AppDelegate.cs is quite large, so I've cut it down for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

Set the Build Action property of `AppDelegate.cs` to Compile.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild your solutions then restart your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing stands out as a problem in the code you have posted.
However, you can try the following :

1. AppDelegate code is missing a 'Window' property. If you have just not added it to your code snippet in the question for brevity, fine. If not, do add it to your app delegate. Both [Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplicationDelegate/) and [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate) mention this in their documentation for ApDelegate and [Storyboards](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/storyboards/).

`public override UIWindow Window { get; set; }`

2. Make sure the `Build action` for you AppDelegate is set to `Compile` and not mistakenly changed to `none` or any other value. This is highly unlikely, but because you mentioned you're going through a huge refactor, this could have been changed accidentally.
3. Similar [problems](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16271/problems-linking-native-library-with-xamarin-ios-7-2-1-42) were [reported](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11272) with different Xamarin.iOS versions before. So try running you project with a different xamarin version setup.
4. Although, i presume, you've tried this multiple times before posting the question, i'd mention : try a complete clean and rebuild. (Manually delete the `bin' and`obj` folders in your iOS project folder, clean the trash, and then do a rebuild just to be sure. Also, try out a full machine restart, remember you're using a Microsoft product!)
5. I also found this weird line in the same [Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplicationDelegate/) documentation, although i am not sure how this can be checked, because the storyboards do not have an owner/AppDelegate reference.

> Application's that are launched from a XIB or storyboard use the
>   UIApplicationDelegate specified in the XIB or storyboard.

Hope either of these steps helps you out. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was some missing reference in the `iOS` project.
Make sure that whatever the `Shared` and the `iOS` projects reference at least the same packages.